# force table to commence on current page, even if it has to split then(2005)

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a report that has a front page provinding some customer details. After that a table is inserted with the list of products ordered by the customer.

Now, the problem is that if the list is to big to fit on the first page (and it fits on the second page, which is possible because the second page doesn't contain all the customer info obv.) it automatically places the table on the second page.

I don't want that, I want the table to begin on the first page, and split & continue on the second page if there's not enough room. Anyone knows how to force this?

(Btw, the property Fit on One page if possible is NOT checked)

Thanks,

Comment: There are some serious bugs in reporting services. .net 4 does not fix them. I have the same issue you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

If your table has fixed height columns, you can try creating a row group, and set the grouping expression to :

```
=Fix((RowNumber("THE_TABLE_NAME")-1) / NUMBER_OF_ROWS_WANTED_PER_PAGE )
```

Replacing THE_TABLE_NAME and NUMBER_OF_ROWS_WANTED_PER_PAGE accordingly.

From : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/61470226-3b96-4b54-975c-8aac1644c08e/